# Date conversion in UTC/ISO 8601 format

Tags: javascript, date, datetime, datetime-conversion

I am working on date conversion.
I am converting this `2017-08-17 13:00:00` format of date to `2017-08-17T13:00:00Z`

working example:

```js
var from_date;
var sdate = new Date( '2017-08-17 13:00:00' );
var utcSDate = sdate.toISOString();
from_date = utcSDate.replace('.000', '');
console.log(from_date);
```

But this code change time from `13:00:00` to `08:00:00`. Why this is happeining. Any idea ?
OR someone give me an idea to convert date from my input to desired output as stated above.

Comment: the toISOString() method converts to UTC, so you need to add the offset to your time

Comment: can you please elaborate about the offset ?

Comment: yes, i wrote an answer

Answer (score 0):

I suggest just to replace the missing parts, without using `Date` object, where you input the local time and get the zulu time.

```js
var date = '2017-08-17 13:00:00',
    iso = date.replace(/(.{10}) (.{8})/, '$1T$2.000Z');

console.log(date);
console.log(iso);
```

Comment: what if the input date format is changed in future? How can it will convert new date format to UTC ?

Answer (score 0):

You can substract the offset from your date object:

```
var d = new Date();
var offsetInMinutes = d.getTimezoneOffset();
d.setMinutes(d.getMinutes() - offsetInMinutes);
d.toISOString()
```

Answer (score 0):

> But this code change time from 13:00:00 to 08:00:00. Why this is
>   happeining. Any idea ? OR someone give me an idea to convert date from
>   my input to desired output as stated above.

The string "2017-08-17 13:00:00" is not a format supported by ECMA-262, so however it is parsed is entirely implementation dependent, see [*Why does Date.parse give incorrect results?*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2587345/why-does-date-parse-give-incorrect-results) If it is parsed to a Date, it is likely to be treated as ISO 8601 local, i.e. as "2017-08-17T13:00:00".  Safari will return an invalid date, Firefox will parse it as local.

So always avoid the built-in parser.

If you just want to reformat the string, do that as a string:

```js
var s = '2017-08-17 13:00:00';
console.log(s.replace(' ','T') + 'Z');
```

However, you have just change the date and time to UTC+0000 from whatever timezone it was in originally. If you want to consider the host timezone offset, then you should parse the string to a date manually (a library can help but isn't necessary for a single format), then use *toISOString*:

```js
// Given a string in ISO 8601 like format, parse as local 
function parseISOLocal(s) {
  var b = s.split(/\D/);
  return new Date(b[0], b[1]-1, b[2], (b[3] || 0),
    (b[4] || 0), (b[5] || 0));
}

var s = '2017-08-17 13:00:00';

console.log(parseISOLocal(s).toISOString())
```